# Why `z || y == 0` does not return what I expect?

Tags: ruby, variables, if-statement

So I am taking the Ruby course in Codecademy and I write this code

```
z = 39
y = 39

if z && y != 39
    print "God if it prints this, this code will be a failure!"
elsif z || y == 0
    print "dont print this code"
else
    print "Success!"
end
```

And for some reason it runs the elsif and says **"dont print this code"** can someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 5):

You have two things to understand here: how && works and how Ruby convert object to true/false.

**How && works:**

You write:

```
if z && y != 39
```

You expect Ruby to interpret like this:

```
if (z != 39) && (y != 39)
```

But actually Ruby interpret it like this:

```
if (z) && (y != 39)
```

**Convert object to true / false**

Any Ruby object that is not nil or false will evaluate to true. So in your case, we have:

```
if z && y != 39
```

Which is:

```
if true && false # z is not nil, so true, and y == 39 so the second part is false
```

which of course evaluate to false.

Then

```
if z || y == 0
```

Which is:

```
if true || false # z is still not nil, y != 0 so the second part is false
```

true || false evaluate to true, so the "dont print this code" is outputted.

Comment: I think you are the only one who actually understood what the OP was trying to accomplish +1

Answer (score 1):

Because `z` being the object is not taken as `false` as you have `z=39`, not set to `boolean` literal value `false` or `nil`

For Ruby any non `nil` or any object set to `boolean` literal value `false` would return `true` in an expression returning `boolean` type value.